Fluentbit adds a "time stdout f" to logs, breaking the json format after update
I am using Fluentbit to collect logs from my EKS cluster and push them to Cloudwatch via cloudwatch-agent.
Recently I have updated the cluster, after that the JSON formatting of my logs started to look weird. Before my logs were like:
{
    "log": {
        "level": "INFO",
        "timestamp": "2024-06-28T03:58:22.248Z"
    }
}

now they look like:
{
    "log": "2024-06-28T03:58:22.24854688Z stdout F {\"timestamp\":\"2024-06-28T03:58:22.248Z\",\"level\":\"INFO\""
}

A weird time stdout F part is added to the beginning of the log line which breaks the json format, and then the rest of the log is a json encoded into a string with escaped characters.
Kubernetes version is 1.29 running with containerd, fluentbit version is 1.9.0. I am using the following parser configuration and input configuration:
[PARSER]
          Name                docker
          Format              json
          Time_Key            timestamp
          Time_Keep           Off
          Time_Format         %Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%LZ

[INPUT]
          Name                tail
          Tag                 application.*
          Exclude_Path        /var/log/containers/cloudwatch-agent*, /var/log/containers/fluent-bit*, /var/log/containers/aws-node*, /var/log/containers/kube-proxy*
          Path                /var/log/containers/*.log
          Docker_Mode         On
          Docker_Mode_Flush   5
          Docker_Mode_Parser  container_firstline
          Parser              docker
          DB                  /var/fluent-bit/state/flb_container.db
          Mem_Buf_Limit       50MB
          Skip_Long_Lines     On
          Refresh_Interval    10
          Rotate_Wait         30
          storage.type        filesystem

